# gridview adapter не передает item в gridview

Tags: gridview

Помогите пожалуйста решить проблему: сделал адаптер gridview но он не работает. в активити вижу что число item передано верно, но текс не передается.
код адаптера

```
package com.example.pyphagof

import android.content.Context
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.BaseAdapter
import android.widget.TextView
import com.example.pyphagof.R

class GridViewAdapter(private val context: Context, private val items: List<String>) : BaseAdapter() {

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return items.size
    }

    override fun getItem(position: Int): Any {
        return items[position]
    }

    override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
        return position.toLong()
    }

    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {
        val gridViewItem: View
        if (convertView == null) {

            gridViewItem = View.inflate(context, R.layout.grid_item, null)
        } else {

            gridViewItem = convertView
        }

        return gridViewItem
    }

    }
```

MainActivity

```
package com.example.pyphagof

import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.GridView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3)
        val items = listOf("Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3")
        val gridView = findViewById<GridView>(R.id.grid_view)
        val adapter = GridViewAdapter(this, items)
        gridView.adapter = adapter
    }
}
```

grid_item

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/item_text1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#DC0A0A"
    android:backgroundTint="#706507"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="18sp" />
```

activity_main3

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/grid_view"
        android:layout_width="415dp"
        android:layout_height="394dp"
        android:numColumns="3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/grid_view"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/grid_view"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/grid_view" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```